# Android: When Clicked on a View dropdown a textView

Tags: java, android, xml

[image]

How Can I achieve this in android? I want to add a feature to my app that when I click this view the view expands and show its content.

Comment: Put several spinners in a recyclerview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to add spinners, this is a pretty straightforward example of expandable recycler view. You can check [this](https://youtu.be/hbMqd0XRN34) for a tutorial